# MongoDB Aggregation - Match if variable is not null

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to write a MongoDB Aggregation query to do the following:

1. I pass a variable to the query method.
2. If the variable is not null, I want to check if it matches.
3. If the variable is null, no match is required

For example:
I pass companyName as a variable and if it is not null, I get records for that company name, otherwise, if it is null, I get records for all company names.

I have come up with something like this: (The match is a part of a larger aggregation query)

```
{ $match : { $and: [ { ?0: { $ne : null }} , {'companyName' : ?0}] }}

List<AggregationGroupSum> getCountByCompany(String companyName)
```

The `?0` is the variable companyName.

I understand that the approach to check it is quite juvenile, but I am new to MongoDB and aggregation query and I would like any help on how to tackle this, whether it be through the aggregation or otherwise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `$or` operator instead of `$and`.

This will fulfill:

1. If `?0` is null, the document is selected.
2. If `?0` is matched with `companyName` value, the document is selected.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $or: [
        { $eq: [?0, null] },
        { $eq: ["$companyName", ?0] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```